# How to integrate angular 8 with CodeIgniter?

Tags: angular, codeigniter

When using angularjs we can integrate angularjs with CodeIgniter with just call the angular libraries.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>angular/app.js"></script>
```

And then just add `ng-app` like this

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
```

And call the controller using `ng-controller`.

But for Angular 8, I have no idea how to do it. All I can find through my searching online is that CodeIgniter just plays as a back-end and angular plays all front-end. Is it possible to use Angular 8 like the way we use angularjs like I mentioned above? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: You cannot do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Angular 2** &  **Above Angular 2** Versions are completely build and structurized as Front End Framework

1. You can  use Angular as Front end & Can Make Rest API in Codeigniter as Backend
2. In Any other way you tried to make Codeigniter App in angular finally you will get stuck on making Build in Angular
3. Conclusion You can't integrate Angular into Codeigniter